# How to get every member's id in a guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to get the id's of everyone in a server this is the code that I'm trying to use.

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def test(ctx):
    for m in list(ctx.guild.members):
        print(m)
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting, and the output you are expecting?

Comment: oh sorry i didnt realize you have to enable intents in the code to use it